# Computing Minimum Description Length

Tags: computer-science, information-theory, entropy

I have two integer arrays, `x` and `y`:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 12,  4],
              [5, 2, 1, 10, 12]]
            )

y = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 11,  4],
              [5, 3, 0, 10, 15]]
            )
```

And I would like to use `x` to compress/compute the description length (in units of "bits") for `y` and then compare the number of "bits saved" as a result of the compression. Given that our data is amll, we'll simply use `n_bits = 8` (8 bits) to store each integer. In the uncompressed case, it takes a total `2 x 5 x 8 = 80` bits to store `y` (i.e., `DL(y) = 80`). Similarly, `DL(x) = 80`. Now, let's assume that `x` is the best possible "model"/"hypothesis" for compressing `y`, then according to the MDL framework:

```
DL(y, x) = DL(y|x) + DL(x)
```

Where `DL(x)` are the number of bits needed to store `x` and `DL(y|x)` is the residual bits of `y` given `x`:

```
residual = x - y

array([[ 0,  0,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 0,  1, -1,  0,  3]])
```

So, what is `DL(y|x)` for this residual array? According to some examples that I've come across (that I don't fully understand), `DL(y|x)` can be computed by first identifying the number of unique values in the residual

```
n_bits = 8
n_unique = len(np.unique(residual))  # 4
DL_residual = 2 * 5 * np.log2(n_unique) + n_unique * n_bits  # 52 bits
```

If I understand correctly, since `n_unique = 4` (i.e., the cardinality of the residual is 4), then it looks like `2 * 5 * np.log2(n_unique)` is accounting for the number of bits to store the residual. However, I have no idea why `n_unique * n_bits` is needed (maybe it is not??). Naively, I would've assumed that `2 * 5 * np.log2(n_unique)` was sufficient.

I don't even know if this even the right way to compute the description length for the residual and, ultimately, I need to figure out what the description length of the residual is.